# Doctrine update schema with PostgreSQL sequence on primary key

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine

I am attempting to wrap a Doctrine model around a legacy database table in PostgreSQL that has:

```
    Column   |           Type           |                      Modifiers                       
 ------------+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------
  id         | integer                  | not null default nextval('table_name_id_seq'::regclass)
```

If I try a mapping like:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", unique=true)
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;
```

Then the schema update tool gives me this:

```
 ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER id DROP DEFAULT;
```

If I try to explicitly define the default, such as:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", unique=true, options={"default"="nextval('table_name_id_seq'::regclass)"})
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;
```

Then it still gives:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER id SET DEFAULT nextval('table_name_id_seq'::regclass);
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER id DROP DEFAULT;
```

And finally, if I try to specify the sequence manually:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", unique=true)
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
 * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="table_name_id_seq", initialValue=1, allocationSize=1)
 */
private $id;
```

I still get the `DROP DEFAULT`:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER id DROP DEFAULT;
```

Is there a workaround for this problem that still allows for the use of the schema update tool? I was not able to find a Doctrine bug relating to this but it's possible I missed something. This is on the latest 2.4.X version of Doctrine running under Symfony 2.5.2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try

`* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")`

Comment: That is indeed what solved it for us (I discussed it in detail in this PR: https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/pull/669). Although the docs suggest(ed?) that choosing `AUTO` would result in a `SERIAL` implementation for PostgreSQL, it turns out that it mapped to `SEQUENCE` instead. So the correct choice is, of course, `IDENTITIY`. To me, this seems to reduce portability between the storage engines, but was a satisfactory solution nonetheless.